# overriding Logger to prepend __MODULE__ in output

Tags: elixir

is it possible in Elixir to override the Logger functions to always prepend the module where it is being called? `"[#{__MODULE__}] "`

like

`Logger.debug("Fetching Exchange Information and Trading Rules...")`

becomes in log:

`[debug] [Elixir.Binance.Futures.Rest.Client] Requesting Exchange Information and Trading Rules...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requested functionality is already there. Just configure `Logger` to output the respective metadata (`:mfa`) as described in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-metadata).

```elixir
config :logger, :console,
  format: "[$level] [$metadata] $message\n",
  metadata: [:error_code, :mfa]
```

Comment: thanks, any way to see just the module name and not the `mfa=` part? `mfa=Binance.Futures.Rest.Client.get_continuous_klines/4`

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin there is a way, but it is soft-deprecated one. You can use `:module` as an metadata key to fetch just module name. It became soft-deprecated (and thus removed from docs) on 1.10.

Comment: @Hauleth I understood the question as “can I get rid of `mfa=` prefix in the metadata output,” in a case of using `:module`, the prefix (`module=` in this case) would stay.

Comment: is there a way to do it only per operation? (and not for all logging on my app)

Comment: Yes, with a custom [`Logger.metadata/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-metadata).